# Separate preview/render border settings possible?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, render-border

I like to render using the cycles in the viewport. To speed things up I use the render border (Ctrl+B) to mark a small region of interest. However when actually render (F12) the border is still there. I know that I can uncheck the box for border before I render. But is there a way to have the viewport use the render and when I go to main render it render the full resolution?

[image: Render border]

Comment: AFAIK, no. but you can use render border while not in the camera view for it only to affect the viewport (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/render-borders-related-check-boxes-how-do-they-work)

Comment: I guess I can live with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. However, [as of blender 2.65](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.65/Cycles#User_Interaction) you can use *Render Border* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) while not in the *Camera view*, which will only affect the viewport:

[image]