# How do I clear the render border?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, render-border

In the 3d viewport I am using a border region to only render things inside the selected region. I did this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. I cannot get rid of the region. How can I make the border disappear?

Comment: Related: [Render Border's related check boxes - How do they work?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2014/599)

Comment: I found this question on a search engine when trying to hide texture borders. The solution was to disable mipmaps in Blender menu "File" -> "User Preferences" -> "System".

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to clear the render border, or if you open the <kbd>Space</kbd> menu and type *"render border"*, you should see the option.

[image]

There is also <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, but this is the legacy shortcut for border render *IIRC* and it only works when looking through the camera. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> as you can have different render borders for the viewport (when doing realtime rendering) and the camera.

Comment: Thorny stuff! `Control Alt B` should really be memorized because it's not the natural inverse / release for `Control B` and without it you're seriously locked-up. Meanwhile, the insidious thing to be emphasized about `Shift B` is that it's the (very useful!) *zoom border* in ALL BUT camera views (where it has the duplicate ["legacy"] function described).

Comment: Wow! I've been struggling with this problem for a long time. Thanks for a solution!

Comment: verbiage changed to 'Clear Render Region'?

Answer (score 6):

On the View Properties Panel (<kbd>N</kbd> to open it) you can find the "Render Border" checkbox. So, select/unselect the chebkbox to enable/disable the render border appearance.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a "border checkbox" in "Properties > Render > Dimensions panel", SteveW posted an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yyjc.png) of the panel [in this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/render-borders-related-check-boxes-how-do-they-work).