# Stop rendering each time camera is moved or anything else is modified

Tags: rendering, camera

For some reason I managed to make the camera render every time I move it to a new position, move an object, modeling or whatever. I want the camera to ONLY render when I hit <kbd>F12</kbd>. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you talking about the "Rendered" Sahding of the vewport? Just change the setting to solid or texture.

Comment: I checked that first, but its solid and it renders every time an adjustment is made to the scene. For example, check this:

http://i59.tinypic.com/34hhra0.png

If I move this cube from position 1 to position 2, it will render after I moved it. Same goes with everything else. Moving stuff around in the scene makes it render each time.

Comment: Then it could be that  you enabled border rendering see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/how-do-i-clear-the-render-border

Answer (score 9):

Well, it sounds like you have your 3DView set to display rendered
[image: viewport render]

try changing it to one of the other settings and see if that fixes the issue.

---

The only other place I can think of to check is the 'autorender' button in the compositor.
try unchecking-that and see if it then only updates the render layer when you hit F12.

Comment: Burril, thanks! That is it! It works now :)

Since lack of information if anyone else stumbles upon the same problem, follow John Burril's advice and uncheck Autorender in the node setup window!

Comment: @Lars you can mark this answer as the solution by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: The autorender button was already unchecked in the compositor; even then everything was getting rendered.  But changing viewport shading to solid fixed the issue for me! thks!!