# Can't see camera outline in camera view and Lock to View not working

Tags: camera

I'm using Blender 2.77 on Linux. Today I must have pressed something - I don't know what - and the camera started to behave strange.

When I press <kbd>NUM 0</kbd>, the view goes to Camera Persp, but I don't get the usual layout (darkened border when just looking from camera perspective and red border when using Lock to View), like this:

[image]

This is certainly something local to the file I'm working on, because when I started Blender again and went to the starting scene, the camera works correctly (as you can see in the screenshot above). This does not happen with my other work file.

Also, when I select Lock to View in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel, I still can't change the view and every test render appears the same because of it.

I searched through all the camera options, probably clicked everything, but I still didn't fix it. I searched here and generally on Google, but there was no answer. I don't even know the name of the option responsible for this behavior, so I can't search efficiently for it.

How to revert my camera to the default behavior?

Comment: maybe related http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6341/19287 , http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2014/19287

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure it's the same thing, but solution from http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26211/23110 did solve the problem.

Comment: @MrZak I didn't provide a screenshot because the situation looked just like any other view - there was nothing special that appeared or changed. The only difference was that it said Camera Persp in the top left corner of the 3D view.

Comment: If you meant that red outline in Camera View like on your screenshot, then that one isn't there by default, it's Render Border used which is drawn by `Ctrl`+`B`. *Camera Persp* will be in the top left corner by default if you enter Camera view.

Comment: Couldn't you just zoom in camera view, so the borders are outside the 3D view window, and then turn on the Lock to view?