# Blender only renders with 20% of CPU

Tags: rendering, hardware

I introduce myself, my name is Kepa and it's my first message in the forum, I wanted to ask for help with a problem that I have when it comes to rendering via CPU. I attached image, of what I comment.
As I commented the problem arises when I render through CPU, I have a workstation with a Dual Xeon 2699 V3-72 Processing threads, when I shoot render in Blender does not use more than 20%, as you will see in the attached image I had to correct it inside Of the performance section of the render tab, the auto threads detected by default puts me 36, that is half of them, I put 72 and nothing, is useless. I do not know if it is due to a Blender problem or that, I work under Max and with the rendering engine works 100% CPU I understand that it is Blender problem.
Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/how-to-render-a-30k-image-with-cycles

Comment: My guess is that the scene is not complex enough to push the CPU to the max, maybe increasing the tile size will have an effect in that direction

Comment: Maybe Blender is not well optimized under Xeon processor and can't fully detect/take advantage of the hardware available

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, you can see that you are only rendering 12 tiles. If you have 72 hyperthreads, then *12 tiles / 72 threads ~= 16% utilisation*. Options:

- Render the [full image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6342/1146), instead of small fraction that you are.

  [image]
- Reduce the render tile size so that you have more tiles rendering at once.

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and later realized that the graphic card (GPU) was near 100% while the main processor (CPU) was only around 20% (see the figure below). I understand this is happening because, in this case, the rendering is happening mostly on the GPU, not the CPU.

[image]