# Persistent Render region will not disappear

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Using blender 2.83. I might misunderstand the terminology but I think the dotted square inside my viewport is the render region? As you can see, even with the checkboxes unchecked it won't disappear.

I've searched everywhere (even found this thread [How do I clear the render border?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/how-do-i-clear-the-render-border)) and all I can find is CTRL + ALT + B, CTRL + B, ALT + B etc etc, to turn it off. I've even disabled it in the preferences, but I cant get rid of this region.

Any ideas what I might have missed?

[image: renderregion checkboxes]

Comment: could it just be the actual camera edge and you're zoomed out? what happens when you press the `Home` key?

Comment: Hello :). You have *Use local camera* checked in your viewport settings :). That's exactly what it does.

Comment: @wilks Is THAT what it is? I come from max and that camera zooms in and out with mousewheel. I pressed home and now that part is zoomed fullscreen. Confusing to say the least. Thank you

Comment: @JachymMichal unchecking will not remove the border, but thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome. you can check `Lock Camera to View`, it might help a bit

Comment: @wilks YES, this is what I needed. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'View' in your viewport (usually at the top), then hover on 'view regions' and select 'clear render region.' If it doesn't work, I'll suggest you update a different version of blender.[image: disable render region]

Comment: Thank you but sadly, this didn't work either. I think I have the newest version. So you mean rollback a version right?