# Faster rendered viewport shading

Tags: animation, materials, 3d-view

I'm trying to preview how a specular material looks on an object when it moves, so I tried rendered viewport shading mode, but this mode is extremely slow even with a very simple object.  So slow that if I play a simple rotation animation nothing draws to the screen.  I'm running an i7 with a GeForce 730m, I feel like I should be getting better performance than this.  Am I missing something here or is it really not possible to preview an animation with materials without rendering a video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rendered shading is the same as a final render ([mostly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2728/599)), so unless you have a very simple scene and a small render farm, you probably aren't going to get even near real-time (as in > 1-2fps) renders.

Some things you can do to help:

- Render a small low resolution part of the viewport (e.g. with render border) See [Render Border's related check boxes - How do they work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2014/599)
- Reduce the number of samples (*Render settings > Sampling*) and bounces (*Render settings > Light paths*)
- If you still want to use the viewport (though I would recommend rendering a quick image sequence), turn down the framerate so each frame has some time to converge.