# Render border settings

Tags: rendering, render-border

In [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/render-borders-related-check-boxes-how-do-they-work) there is a screenshot showing the ability to set render border settings. However when I use Ctrl-b and select an area I don't see these settings in the options area, it just shows the text "Set Render Border" with a blank area (Blender 2.73b).  Was this ability removed?

I'm mainly interested in these settings to see if they can be interpolated in an animation.

Comment: Does this help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45837/3710 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to alter the values has been removed. Adjusting the values was removed in 2.69. Up until 2.71 you could adjust the camera only option.

While you may not be able to adjust the values from the operator you can access and adjust the values used for the border. For the final render they can be found at `scene.render.border_max_x`... Note that min to max values are 0.0 to 1.0 so the clipping is a percentage of the render size. You should be able to alter these values in a [frame_change_pre handler](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/bpy.app.handlers.html).

I think cropping the image in the compositor would be a better approach. You can keyframe the settings of a crop node to move it around.

[image]

Some other options are to animate a mask in the movie clip editor (part of the camera tracking) or use object pass index and animate an object to create the mask.

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestions. I specifically wanted to do this without using scripting. I thought that it would be a way that I could divide the processing of an image's render for use with a renderfarm like sheepit that doesn't allow scripts to run.  The masking approach might work.

Comment: I don't recommend using the Crop node nor a mask as both will still render the entire frame. Instead, I'd recommend using the [animated render border](https://blendermarket.com/products/animated-render-border/) add-on. It allows you to animate the borders and also tweak their values.

Comment: Which adjusts the [render border](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings.border_max_x) settings that I mention in the second paragraph and later expanded on in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38223109/2684771) of using it. I suggested the crop node here as the question isn't about python so I suggested a more user friendly approach to animating the cropping.