# Noise in rendered image even with 1000 samples

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

[image]

[image]

Rendered with 1000 samples in cycles. What can i try to get rid of it without losing the quality of the image?

Comment: Apart from the builtin denoiser mentioned in Aubrey's answer, there are also other free denoiser like [OIDN](https://github.com/OpenImageDenoise/oidn)

Comment: TBH 1000 samples is not that much. Read: [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles/86225#86225), [Managing/Reducing noise in a night scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30407/managing-reducing-noise-in-a-night-scene) and [Which denoiser is better?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166269/which-denoiser-is-better/166271#166271) ...and there is even more here...

Comment: Yes, thanks for linking the treads. My bad, couldn't have found enough information thru google.

Comment: You're welcome! Great posts and worth reading. Also, I'd recommend use the render border to figure out how many samples really needed in the first place: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88177/31447 Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Intel's Denoiser](https://openimagedenoise.github.io/) - assuming you are rendering with Cycles engine.

1. In the Layer Properties tick 'Denoising Data'
2. Switch to the Compositor Editor or Compositing Workspace from the top Menu or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
3. Make sure you tick 'Use Nodes' to activate Nodes in the Compositor
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add a Node, Search > Denoise; connect as in the screenshot below
5. Render

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to properly connect the Denoise node in Compositor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173761/31447)