# How do i get rid of this red dotted rectangle?

Tags: modeling

I can't figure out how to get rid of this red dotted line in the middle of the viewport.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The red checkered box is a render region.
It's used to render only parts of your screen.

Clear it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
Or through *View > View Regions*

[image]

Read: [Render Border's related check boxes - How do they work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/render-borders-related-check-boxes-how-do-they-work)