# How To Delete This Red Box on My Screen?

Tags: 3d-view

I was editing my mesh and I wanted to only see a part of my mesh, so I pressed alt+B to only show a selected area. However, I did **ctrl**+B and created a red rectangle on my screen (I don't know what it does).

Does anybody know how to get it off?

[image]

Comment: [Set Render Region](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/regions.html) Press Ctrl-Alt-B to clear. : )

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The red checkered box is a render region.
It's used to render only parts of your screen.

You can clear it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Or through *View > View Regions*

[image]

Read: [Render Border's related check boxes - How do they work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/render-borders-related-check-boxes-how-do-they-work)

Comment: I guess my comment wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Fjoersteller your comment should be an answer since it totally resolve the problem

Comment: Thanks so much!